# How can I iterate over a template literal union type?

Tags: typescript, types

I need to iterate over a string union type generated via template literals.

```
type Foo = "Foo" | "Foo2" | "Foo3";

type Bar = "Bar" | "Bar2" | `${Foo}Type`;
```

I want to iterate over all the values of `Bar` at runtime. Typically, this is accomplished via a `<const>` assertion like so:

```
const Bar = ["Bar", "Bar2"] as const;
export type BarType = typeof Bar[number];

Bar.forEach((value) => {console.log(value)});
```

Attempting this with a template literal doesn't seem to be possible because types aren't available at runtime.

```
const Bar = ["Bar", "Bar2", `${Foo}Type`] as const;
```

If this isn't possible, what would be the best way to accomplish this design?

How can I create a type composed from another type that can be used at both runtime and compile time?

Comment: Typescript compiles into JS so you won't have any type info at runtime.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/weQBKw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in a reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz That seems like it's perfect! Can you explain exactly what's going on with that suffix function? Lots of advanced typescript there that's blowing my mind. <3

Comment: I simplified it a bit; `suffix()` kept track of the exact order of the output array, but you don't need that.  In fact, you can get what you want without any type assertions.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks so much for your answer! This is exactly what I needed. Would you mind explaining what the `suffix()` function is and does anyway? It looks like it's using a pretty powerful part of Typescript that I know nothing about.

Comment: The input of `suffix` a string array of type `T` and a string of type `U` and the return type is `{ [I in keyof T]: \`${T[I]}${U}\` }`, which is a [mapped array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  For every numeric index `I` in the input array type `T`, the corresponding output array element is of type `\`${T[I]}${U}\``, meaning it's the concatenation of the `I`th element of `T`  and `U`.  So if `T` is `["x","y","z"]` and `U` is `"?"`, then the mapped type becomes `["x?","y?","z?"]`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @jcalz That makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create JavaScript values from TypeScript types; the static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript.  So `type Foo` and `type Bar` will not be available to help you create `const Foo` and `const Bar`.  Your only hope is to make values and then use those to help you create types.

Your `Foo` type is easy enough to make:

```
const Foo = ["Foo", "Foo2", "Foo3"] as const;
type Foo = typeof Foo[number];
```

The [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) allows the compiler to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the elements of `Foo`, and from there you can get the union of those element types by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Foo` with a `number` key.

---

But `Bar` is trickier.   Here is the simplest way I can think of to do it:

```
const Bar = ["Bar", "Bar2", ...Foo.map(t => `${t}Type` as const)] as const;
console.log(Bar);
// const Bar: readonly ["Bar", "Bar2", ...("FooType" | "Foo2Type" | "Foo3Type")[]]

type Bar = typeof Bar[number];
// type Bar = "Bar" | "Bar2" | "FooType" | "Foo2Type" | "Foo3Type"
```

Here I've used the [`map()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to append `"Type"` onto every element of `Foo`.

First, note that the callback is `` t => `${t}Type` as const `` with its own `const` assertion.  That tells the compiler that you'd like it to figure out what the [template literal *expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `` `${t}Type` `` evaluates to as a [template literal *type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types). (This behavior was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707).)  Since `t` is inferred as type `Foo`, then `` `${t}Type` as const `` is inferred as type `` `${Foo}Type` ``, which is what you wanted.

The [TypeScript call signature for the array `map()` method](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1237) returns an unordered array type, not a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like the type of `Foo`.  So the compiler doesn't know that, for example, the second element is `"Foo2Type"`.  All it knows is that the array is of type `` Array<`${Foo}Type`> ``.  If you cared about order, we'd need to do something else.  But since you don't, this is sufficient.

Anyway, the `const Bar = ["Bar", "Bar2", ...Foo.map(✂) as const] as const` line has another `const` assertion, which tells the compiler to keep track of `"Bar"` and `"Bar2"`.  So the type of the `Bar` value is inferred as:

```
// const Bar: readonly ["Bar", "Bar2", ...("FooType" | "Foo2Type" | "Foo3Type")[]]
```

And so if you ask the compiler what the element type is, by indexing into `typeof Bar` with `number`, you get:

```
type Bar = typeof Bar[number];
// type Bar = "Bar" | "Bar2" | "FooType" | "Foo2Type" | "Foo3Type"
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYiEMC8MDaAiBIMBoZaIBMeB2AzBgLowCGEMokUA3ALABQUAngA4Cm8RChg8BIAGZCQaMAFcAtgCN+AJyrsOAei2i+g7CMI4YAHzLEMZiyEqdOTaDABCtVSMyvVpDF5L4AOiDsAIVaXgAKWGQAPhgAAwASAG8oAF8AFX14ugZHKABKGnpGcGhNRxAAG34AqpAAcwivAs0dUuYXNwAuGFV+WgATcCrudF83Hz9SIICI4yyBK3NjIkX+ZZtydYwCtCoqey59LvdUMX5JU9lFFXU23QvToy9NidUSawX9N+w1n6+FB2RyAA)